# Trying to pass the values of an array to the component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get a single value (for that specific component) from an array. The thing is that I want to get single value but not every value in my array (for example everything about Vodka). Because my component doesn't handle dynamic route properly and the page is blank, it is obviously problem with an array.

But here is the warning message which I get: ***Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/vue-next
at <SingleDrink SingleDrink= (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]***

This is how my array looks like (from **Drinks.vue**):

```
data(){
    return{
    drinks: [
                    {product:"Wine", price: 149.99, url: require('../assets/images/grasevina.jpg')},
                    {product:"Beer", price: 12.99, url: require('../assets/images/corona.jpg')},
                    {product:"Vodka Smirnoff", price: 119.99, url: require('../assets/images/smirnoff.jpg')},
                    {product:"Cocktail Malibu", price: 89.99, url: require('../assets/images/malibu.jpg')},
                    {product:"Jack Daniels Honey", price: 169.99, url: require('../assets/images/jack_daniels.jpg')},
                    {product:"Strawberry liqueur", price: 149.99, url: require('../assets/images/liker-malina.jpg')}    
                ],
}
},
```

the logic of passing values on the component (**Drinks.vue**):

```
 <div v-if="drinks.length">
  <div v-for="drink in drinks" :key="drink.product">
    <SingleDrink :SingleDrink="drink"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the template section where I'm trying to fetch single value from array (**SingleDrink.vue component**):

```
<div id="SingleDrink">
    <h1>{{SingleDrink.product}}</h1> 
</div>
```

These are the props (**SingleDrink.vue component**):

```
props: {
  SingleDrink: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
```

This is the `v-for` that is used to represent every item from an array (**Home.vue**):

```
<div class="col-sm-4" v-for="(items) in items" :key=items.id>
                            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                                <div class="single-products">
                                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                                            <img :src="items.url" alt="" />
                                            <h2>{{items.price}} kn</h2>
                                            <p>{{items.product}}</p>
                                            <router-link to="/cart" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</router-link>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-overlay">
                                            <div class="overlay-content">
                                                <h2>{{items.cijena}} kn</h2>
                                                <p>{{items.proizvod}}</p>
                                                <button @click.prevent="route(items)" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart">Details</button>
                                                <router-link to="/cart" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</router-link>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="choose">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to favorite</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate? what is your exact requirement here?

Comment: @Shreeraj I updated my question in more detail.

Comment: Can you show us the markup?

Comment: Please add more code related to this code `<SingleDrink SingleDrink= (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`. It seems like you have an error in the component `<SingleDrink>`. Also add how are you trying get the value from the array, the logic for it.

Comment: @Shreeraj so I updated my question again and added more code. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are trying to pass whole array in your child component `SingleDrink` and then accessing it as a single drink and because of that you are facing this issue.

**Solution:** You need to use `v-for` on the `div` element and then pass each product (which is `drink` in this case) in the `SingleDrink` child component over the iteration.

Additionally we have added `v-if` condition so that `v-for` only executes if and only if there are some elements in the `drinks` array.

Look at the below code for better understanding:

```html
<template v-if="drinks.length">
   <div v-for="drink in drinks" :key="drink.product">
      <SingleDrink :single-drink="drink" />
   </div>
</template>
```

---

Inside your `SingleDrink` component:

```html
<div id="SingleDrink">
    <h1>{{ SingleDrink.product }}</h1>
</div>
```

```js
props: {
  SingleDrink: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
},
```

Here with this above code, you will have single object with all the details of the product in your child component `SingleDrink`

*Additional Info: It's good practice at add `type` and `required` properties while using `props`.*

Comment: Thanks for this! But when this is applied in my console I'm getting looped the same value of that array in many times. And the page is still blank.
For example: ```at <SingleDrink SingleDrink= {product: 'Wine', price: 149.99, url: '/img/grasevina.a2d65e9d.jpg'}
  at <SingleDrink SingleDrink= {product: 'Wine', price: 149.99, url: '/img/grasevina.a2d65e9d.jpg'}
  at <SingleDrink SingleDrink= {product: 'Wine', price: 149.99, url: '/img/grasevina.a2d65e9d.jpg'}
  at <SingleDrink SingleDrink= {product: 'Wine', price: 149.99, url: '/img/grasevina.a2d65e9d.jpg'}```

Comment: add your implemented code here.. so I can have a look at it. what do you mean by applied in console?

Comment: I updated it now exactly how it looks from my code. I wrote the sentence wrong. Let me correct it: When this is applied I'm getting looped the same value of that array in many times (those warnings are displayed in my console)

Comment: have used `for` loop somewhere else? it should not show same value inside `v-for`. can you please recheck?

Comment: I have another ```v-for``` which is used to represent values from an array of every different product. And when specific is selected I want details of that specific value. Is there a problem with that ```v-for```?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246611/discussion-between-shreeraj-and-jan-tudan).

Comment: I added more code of another ```v-for```. I also added the name of a single file 
for each code snippet.

Comment: Hey! Could you answer me in the chat please?